# Group results from two different tables on same hours

Tags: mysql, join, select, datetime

I have two simple tables:

**indoor**

```
id | timestamp | temp | humi
```

**outdoor**

```
id | timestamp | temp
```

And two selects which give me time and average temperature grouped by same hour for the last 24 hours:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%H:00') AS time, round(avg(temp), 1) as avg_out_temp
FROM outdoor
WHERE timestamp >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
ORDER BY timestamp ASC;

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%H:00') AS time, round(avg(temp), 1) as avg_in_temp
FROM indoor
WHERE timestamp >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```

And now what I need to do is to group those two results by same hour, with respect to possibility that there can be no records in **indoor** or **outdoor** table for whole hour, so I need to get:

```
time | avg_out_temp | avg_in_temp
11:00 | 12.5 | 21.4
12:00 | 13.9 | null
13:00 | null | 22.4
14:00 | 14.0 | 22.5
```

I'm working with MariaDB:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.41-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf (armv7l) using readline 5.2
```

Comment: Specify MySQL version

Comment: Is it possible to have a row with `NULL` in both temp columns?  That is, no data indoor or outdoor for that hour?  If so, is it OK to skip that row in the output?

Comment: @RickJames yes it's possible, in this case it can be skipped.

Comment: @elementstyle - Or you can `LEFT JOIN` from a table with 24 hours to nulls (or zeros, via `COALESCE`).

Answer (score 1):

Because both your queries return the same number (and type) of fields, the can be combinied with `UNION ALL`. The `ORDER BY` is only needed once at then end of the query.

To see the difference between `indoor` and `outdoor` this could be added to your query.

```
SELECT 'out' as door,DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%H:00') AS time, round(avg(temp), 1) as avg_out_temp
FROM outdoor
WHERE timestamp >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'in' as door,DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%H:00') AS time, round(avg(temp), 1) as avg_in_temp
FROM indoor
WHERE timestamp >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has no full out join, this is why it hast to be simulated.
So iz os quit ugly.

```
SELECT IFNULL(ti.time,tou.time) time,ti.avg_in_temp,tou.avg_out_temp
FROM 
((SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H') timecon
,MIN(DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%H:00')) AS time
, round(avg(temp), 1) as avg_in_temp
FROM indoor
WHERE `timestamp` >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
) ti LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H') timecon 
,MIN(DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%H:00')) AS time
, round(avg(temp), 1) as avg_out_temp
FROM outdoor
WHERE `timestamp` >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
) tou on ti.timecon = tou.timecon)
union
SELECT IFNULL(ti.time,tou.time) time,ti.avg_in_temp,tou.avg_out_temp
FROM 
((SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H') timecon
,MIN(DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%H:00')) AS time
, round(avg(temp), 1) as avg_in_temp
FROM indoor
WHERE `timestamp` >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
) ti RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H') timecon 
,MIN(DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%H:00')) AS time
, round(avg(temp), 1) as avg_out_temp
FROM outdoor
WHERE `timestamp` >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
) tou on ti.timecon = tou.timecon)
ORDER BY time ASC;
```

I removed the sorting from Select from indoor and outdoor, because it is not needed.
[herer you find an examle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ecad52cfd9827ba068349166c431c1ae)

Of course, because of your where clause you have to have **timestamps that are not older than one day**, so the select query won't return nothing in the exqamle